# PyTest with SQLAlchemy teardown sessions

Tags: python, flask, pytest

Im trying to create sessions so I can rollback test data with PyTest, I think im close but right now its loading the test data in but no rollbacks are happening

My code as follows:

```py
engine = create_engine(url)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class TestApps:

    @pytest.fixture
    def client(self):
        return app.test_client()

    @pytest.fixture
    def mock_verify(self):
        # Create a mock object
        mock = patch("flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators.verify_jwt_in_request")
        # Start the patch and return the mock object
        yield mock.start()
        # Stop the patch
        mock.stop()

    def setup_class(self):
        self.session = Session()

    def teardown_class(self):
        self.session.rollback()
        self.session.close()

    @patch('flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators.verify_jwt_in_request')
    def test_create_app(self, mock_verify, client):
        self.setup_class()
        mimetype = "application/json"
        headers = {"Content-Type": mimetype}
        data = {
            "app_name": "Fire Dampers",
            "short_code": "TFF",
            "icon": "icon2.png"
        }

        response = client.post('/application/create', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

        assert response.status_code == 200

        self.teardown_class()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `assert` in `test_create_app` fails, you will never call your `teardown_class` function.

You should make your session a pytest [yield fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#teardown-cleanup-aka-fixture-finalization):

```
class TestApp:

    @pytest.fixture
    def session(self):
        self.session = Session()
        yield
        self.session.rollback()
        self.session.close()

    @patch('flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators.verify_jwt_in_request')
    def test_create_app(self, mock_verify, client, session):
        mimetype = "application/json"
        headers = {"Content-Type": mimetype}
        data = {
            "app_name": "Fire Dampers",
            "short_code": "TFF",
            "icon": "icon2.png"
        }

        response = client.post('/application/create', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

        assert response.status_code == 200
```

Note that it is not clear from your example how `self.session` relates to your application, so you may have other things that need fixing.